# What does "he" in "he back" refer to?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010), Harry says to Ron, who was upset about Harry being closer to Hermoine:

> Harry: What part of this isn't living up to your expectations? Did you
> think we were gonna he staying in a hotel? Finding a Horcrux every
> other day? Thought you'd **he** back by  Christmas?

What does "he" in "he back" refer to?

Comment: Possibly a typo?

Comment: Did this happen in the movie? I think it would be better to add the video link then. Because this seems more like a typo in the subtitles to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a typo.  The text should probably read:

> Well then, I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand. What part of this
> isn't living up to your expectations? Did you think we were gonna be
> staying in a five-star hotel? Finding a Horcrux every other day? You
> thought you'd be back with your mum by Christmas?